# Convert Numpy matrix values to be float32

Tags: python, numpy

I want to enforce the values in the eigenvector matrix below to be of type `float32` to save memory space instead of using `float64`. However, it seems the way I did below `eigenvectors.astype(np.float32)` does not work. Is there a work around of that?

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph(edges)
L = nx.laplacian_matrix(G)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors.astype(np.float32) = np.linalg.eig(L.todense())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `np.linalg.eig` function returns arrays of the same `dtype` as its parameter.

So you have two choices:

1. Try `np.linalg.eig(L.todense().astype(np.float32))`. (This might overflow)
2. Convert the eigenvectors later.

The second option goes like this:

```
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(L.todense())
eigenvectors = eigenvectors.astype(np.float32)
```